# List in the WIFI

Tags: android, list, wifi

I am facing some difficulty including the WIFI code inside my application. I am not posting a question unless I've tried everything, my only doubt that maybe it is because of the WIFI listing.

The following code is added to my MainActivity outside the OnCreat function.

```
protected void onPause() {
unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
super.onResume();
}


class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();//getting the scan result into a list

//........................................................
wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i).BSSID).toString()+" , "
        + String.valueOf(wifiScanList.get(i).level) +" , " + String.valueOf(wifiScanList.get(i).frequency));

Log.e("WIFI", " :  " + wifis[i]);

//........................................................

}

list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));
```

And it is working great alone, but I get the following error when I try to run in and it force close my App.

```
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x8000010 } in ash.email.MainActivity$WifiScanReceiver@429f8288
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 21:19:45.206: E/AndroidRuntime(8530): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 21:53:53.436: E/AndroidRuntime(10258):    at ash.email.MainActivity$WifiScanReceiver.onReceive(MainActivity.java:252)
03-30 21:53:53.436: E/AndroidRuntime(10258):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
03-30 21:53:53.436: E/AndroidRuntime(10258):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Read the stack trace below `Caused by`, then figure out what is null.

Comment: I know, I always search for caused by but what may cause a NullPointerException!!?? the problem is the WifiScanReceiver class but i couldn't figure it out!! Do you think for any reasons the list should be converted into listArray? @SLaks

Comment: Something in your code is null. You need to use a debugger to figure out what.